# Android different databases for different users

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication

I want to see if there is a way to assign different database names to different users that login to an app. I'm trying to write a small app that assigns a DB to a user based on their username/email.

I tried setting DATABASE_NAME that is passed into

```
public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

to the users' email addresses but it doesn't work. It loads the same data for all users.

On logout, I close the database and clean up and on startup, everytime I start a new database connection with the name already properly assigned...

Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the name of the database to your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class constructor (along with required Context instance) instead of hardcoding it as did `DATABASE_NAME`:

```
public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBOpenHelper(Context context, String dbName, int dbVersion) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    }
...
}
```